# Changing Password using prompt withing Apex Application

Tags: authentication, oracle-apex

I have an Apex application that currently has a login page with credentials I entered into a table, manually, called CSD_LOGIN_USERS.
I'm able to make it work using a function called CSD_LOGIN_AUTH.

So right now all users can login to the app with the password I defined but they can't change it and I, obviously, can see their passwords in the table even if another ADMIN updates it.

How can I:-

Implement the prompt to update that password?

Prevent user from ever being prompted again to change password at login (except they decide to change)?

Encrypt/hide the passwords in the PASSWORD Column?

My version of APEX is 22.1

Answer (score 0):

NEVER store actual passwords, encrypted or not, in the database. There should never be a way to directly view or decrypt the actual password values. Rather, use a hashing function (like SHA256) in the DBMS_CRYPTO package or in JavaScript to generate a one-way hash of the password to store in the database. When the user logs in, hash the password they provide and compare that to the stored hash in the table.

Implement the change password functionality just like you'd implement a screen to change any other data in the database. Pass the new password through the hashing function to get the value to store.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. On your table CSD_LOGIN_USERS, add a column `expiry_date DATE`. In the application, check the expiry date for a user in before header branch of the home page. If the expiry date is in the past, then branch to a "Change Password" page. This can probably be implemented as part of the login process as well - if password is expired redirect to change password after login. This is the "prompt to change password".

Implement the "change password" page. There are plenty of examples on the web on how to do that. I just googled "oracle apex custom password page" and got a several blogs explaining how to do it.

In the "change password" page, define a hidden page item on expiry date and set it with a computation to a date in the future (100 years ?). This will ensure that the user is not prompted for a change. If, at some point in time, the companies' security policy is updated to require regular password updates (as is required in most places now), then you just need to set other values for the expiry date.

encrypt passwords: use a modern hashing function and *never* store the password in clear text. Just store the hashed password. [Here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/storing-passwords-in-the-database-9i) is an old blog that explains exactly what you need to know. Do note that there are more secure hashing functions now. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67889261/using-hash-sha-256) is an example stack overflow answer.

To make the implementation future proof, I'd add a user pwd history table. Most modern security policies require that a password cannot be any of the last x passwords to avoid users cycling through 2 passwords.

In addition to this, you probably also need "reset password" functionality. If the user forgets his password it cannot be retrieved since only hash function is stored. You could send an email with a link to a "RESET password" page.